# How to get stringValue from a NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I am creating a OSX Cocoa Application using Swift. I am trying to get the input from a NSTextView to my paste board.

```
@IBOutlet var issues: NSTextView!

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {
    let stringvalue = "Issue: \(issues.StringValue)"
    let pasteboard = NSPasteboard.general()
    pasteboard.declareTypes([NSPasteboardTypeString], owner: nil)               
    pasteboard.setString(stringvalue, forType: NSPasteboardTypeString)
}
```

The only error that I am getting is "Value of type 'NSTextView' has no member 'stringValue'.

I don't want to use NSTextField since that only lets me use one line.

Comment: @Leo Dabus not stringValue

Comment: actually just `issues.string` NSTextView
 is a subclass of the 
NSText
 class

Comment: @LeoDabus - When I use issues.string the output shows this Optional(\n\n\n) - I just want plain text. How do I change that.

Comment: You just need to use if let to unwrap the optional value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTextView is a subclass of the NSText class. So you need to get your string using NSText [string](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstext/1528601-string) property:

```
if let string = issues.string {
    let stringvalue = "Issue: \(string)"
    print(stringvalue)
}
```

Comment: Now what if I have multiple string values. Example: `let stringvalue = "Customer Name: \(customername.stringValue)\nProduct Type: \(prodtype.stringValue) \nSerial #: \(serial.stringValue)` .   How would I include the Issue part?

Comment: What do you mean include the issue? you can simply use `+` sign to add it to the end of your string or use string interpolation.

Comment: So if you want to add it as an extra line just add `"\nIssue: \(string)"`

Comment: Last question, if I wanted multiple textviews how would that work under a single button function?

Comment: @Brenny feel free to open a new question detailing what you are trying to accomplish. Your question  as it is now it's too vague. If you would like you can also just edit this question and add the additional info. Btw with 15 pts reputation you can already vote up the answers that you think it is correct.

Comment: Note that you probably don't even need a button for that. You can monitor your text fields or  text views to automatically change the other after the text changes or when the editing is finished